# Implementing joint learning in keras

Tags: deep-learning, convolution, conv-neural-network, keras

i am trying to implement a model that is composed of two layers to segment object candidates in keras
So basically this model has the following architecture

Image(channel,width,height) -> multiple convolution and pooling layers- > output('n' feature maps , height width )

Now this ***single output*** is being used by two layers
which are as follows
1) convolution (1*1) - > dense layer with m units (output = n * 1*1 )  - > pixel classifier using fully connected layers of h*w dimesion -> upsmapling to (H,N) - > output

2) convolution -> maxpooling->dense layer - > score

Cost function uses outputs of both these layers which is sum of binary logistic regression of each output

Now I have two questions
1) how to implement dense connection over  convoluted output in layer 1 to produce h*w pixel classifier as mentioned above
2) How to merge  the two layers to calculate the single cost function and then train both the layers jointly using back-propagation

Can anyone tell me how to create the model for above mentioned network architecture.i am new to deep learning so if there something which i misunderstood i ll appreciate if anyone can explain me the errors in my understanding
Thanks

Comment: The model i am trying to implement is similar to to the one mentioned in the following paper where it trains the two layers based on joint binary logistic cost function using alternate backpropagation, between the two layers as mentioned in the paper - (arxiv.org/pdf/1506.06204).  Is there any model in keras which has implementation close to this model .?

Answer (score 0):

It's easier when you share the code you already have.

For the transition convolution to dense, you have to use `model.add(Flatten())`, like in the [examples here](http://keras.io/examples/).

Unfortunately, I don't know for the second question, but according to what I just read in the Keras Models, you have to use the graph model.

Comment: The model i am trying to implement is similar to  to the one mentioned in the following paper where it trains the two layers based on joint binary logistic cost function using alternate backpropagation, between the two layers as mentioned in the paper -       (arxiv.org/pdf/1506.06204)

Comment: It seems that you have to use a graph model.

Comment: Yeah i just went through and implemnted the same but i am stuck at the part where i have to apply alternate backpropagation through each of the layers, can you guide me as to what exactly this means i am confused

Comment: Sorry, I don't know it well enough :-(

Comment: Thanks for your effort ..:)